# OpenGL3.2 GLSL blocky interpolation

Tags: opengl, geometry, glsl, gradient

I am wanting a nice gradient effect. But at the minute its really patchy and you can see a seem between the two triangles. I have the following shaders vert and frag. The only thing I can think to do is to swap to a pre-generated texture.

The data is buffed as floats [x y][R G B] for two triangles, I don't think that the C++ source is worth showing.

VERT
    #version 330

```
layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;    
layout(location = 1) in vec3 incolor;

smooth out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    color = incolor;
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x,position.y,0.0,1.0);  
}
```

FRAG
    #version 330

```
smooth out vec4 outputColor;
smooth in vec3 color;

void main()
{
    outputColor  = vec4(vec3(color),1.0);   
}
```

RESULT
[image: blocky]

Looking at the single triangle shows the blocky-ness 
[image]

Comment: You might find you get more precision by sticking the colour to be interpolated into a tex-coord between the vertex and the fragment shader.

Comment: @JasonD: There's no such thing as a "tex-coord"; there are only user-defined interpolated values.

Comment: @Andrew: How do you know this is an interpolation problem and not a problem with your display bitdepth, screen, or how you're visualizing it?

Comment: Could you please provide the attribute data (colors) of this example output?

Comment: @NicolBolas Because he shows us the raw output... I don't think that this image has been further manipulated. Things like screen and gamma correction don't affect screenshots.

Comment: @NicolBolas just because GL doesn't have semantics, doesn't mean that the implementation doesn't sometimes choose to infer things it shouldn't.

Comment: Andrew, do you complain about the diagonal being distorted in some way, or about the colors not being smooth (steps after each 10 pixels or so)? Because the second is a limitation of your bitdepth of the buffer (however, you can tweak this in the fragment shader -- I'm thinking about a dithering effect, which is used in professional software to display images with higher bitrates (16, 32 bits) on 8 bit screens and can be done in a fragment shader, too)

Comment: steps after each 10 pixels is my problem :) Sorry that I made it a two parter. But yes the stepping is my main issue. I sort of have you're solution implemented now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a correct behavior of *linear interpolation* of attributes of a **quad**. Remember that a quad is always rendered as two triangles. There are two possibilities to do so: with a `\` diagonal or a `/` diagonal as their common edge. How the attribute is interpolated now becomes ambiguous (is different in the both cases).

I'll show you an example similar to yours.

[image]

Triangles are separated by a `\` diagonal.

[image]

Triangles are separated by a `/` diagonal.

In both cases, the colors of the vertices are:

```
000000  top left
3B3B3B  top right + bottom left
FFFFFF  bottom right
```

A solution is to provide only attribute values (colors) which result in unambiguous interpolated colors. This is the case when the following holds.

Consider a line from the top left to the bottom right corner (let's call these the base vertices with an assigned base color). The top left corner has a value of `0`, the bottom right `1`. Every other vertex (in this case bottom left, top right) has to be projected orthogonally to this imaginary line and the corresponding value is assigned to this vertex. In this case (a square) the two other corners have a value of `.5` each. The colors of these corners have to be a mix value of the two base colors with an alpha value corresponding to the value just calculated.

In the example above, the colors of the two other corners had to be `808080` instead of `3B3B3B` in order to make both images look equally:

[image]

In your case, you use the following colors for the vertices (at least, they appear as such in your screenshot):

```
000000  top left
3A3A3A  top right + bottom left
595959  bottom right
```

So they don't fulfill the requirement from above, as `3A3A3A` isn't the mean value between the other twos.

---

A slightly different example demonstrates why you maybe don't just want to use `.5` for the mix alpha value (which results in mean values for the two other vertices). Consider a non-square quad, like this rectangle, which uses values `.5` for the two other corners, which corresponds to `808080` gray:

[image]

As you can see, the direction of the gradient isn't orthogonal to the connection line between the two "base corners", as I called them (top left -- bottom right). Now let's see what my method from above produces:

[image]

Which looks more like a linear gradient between the two corners, but in "world space", not in "texture space". You might prefer one of the two outputs over the other; I wanted to show you the difference. The values on the connection line (orthogonal projection) look like the following (they are only approximations!)

[image]

<sub>Sorry for my bad images... ;)</sub>

Comment: P.S. The same holds for the vertex coordinates... Consider a quad (a floor tile in a raster tile world), one of the corners having a height of 1, the others 0. The diagonal decides if the center of the tile is at height 0 or at 0.5, just as an exemplary point. This is the reason why we normally avoid quads if the input data is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

So that solves the issue with the seem. And I understand now what I was trying to do was impossible. Since there is no way for each triangle to know what the color on the other side of the seem.

So how about the second part of the question how come I am getting a blocky/striped effect.

Comment: @Andrew Just added a comment to your question. Look up "dithering", this should give you the theoretical background. You want to map floating point values to 255 discrete steps from 0 to 1 (which build up the image on your screen); however, you should not round them at a threshold in between (which is what the graphics card does per default for you automatically) but rather decide the threshold value depending on the pixel coordinate. Sounds complicated, but brings nice results.

Comment: This demonstrates the same, but with other bitrates (so you can see it better on a 24bbp (= 8 bit channel depth) screen): http://www.fragment.fi/2011/02/dithering-images-for-16-bit-displays/

Comment: I haven't had any look fixing the banding issue :(